# Why is typescript complaining on the below code?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following typing:

```
interface HookableTrait {}
type promotionMeta = any;

interface PromotionController<TPromotionData extends promotionMeta = any, TTransferData extends any = any, TSerializableObject extends object = object> extends HookableTrait {}
abstract class PromotionController<TPromotionData extends promotionMeta = any, TTransferData extends any = any, TSerializableObject extends object = object> {}
```

Why am I getting a `TS2428: All declarations of 'PromotionController' must have identical type parameters.` error here?

Here's a playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIHt0Gs4CMA2EAKlHMGMgN4C%20AUGAJ4AOKTU6AtumMOiALIQwcZAF5kcEAwDctWqEixEKAArsuPPgGE%20YdvkJQAPETWduvEABE4w5BAAekEABMAzsjbnNAoSPGSDAA0yEQkkm4w0DZ2js7uElJiicGhAMrQwHD4wABeeIQA8rgAVhAIFHEQrh7opeUU4nVlFQB89k7VCRjYBcSk5FR0eG56iBQI%20HBuHmYaljrg%20oYmcxZ8MSJVNZ7q6752AVIhYaQgkdG2W507gcmBJxlQWTn5BBDFLZU3Cc0NyX82kMgA) also.

Comment: you can set: let promotionMeta: any;

Comment: what does that have to do with anything? how would that solve this error?